# Streaming a set of videos as in playlist without gap in transition

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-video, video.js

I have been making a ***player***. I should display a set of videos in a queue by reading from a directory.

*This is how the videos are listed in my videos folder:*

**1.** *first_video.mp4*

**2.** *second_video.mp4*

**3.** *third_video.mp4*

**Ex.** When the first video ends, I have to display the second video right after.

*The issue* I am facing is that there is a gap to buffer next video. What I want is to display all these videos as one video, so that I would not have gaps in switching from video to video.

*Are there any **js video players** to solve this problem or libraries?*

Could it be accomplished using PHP or js?

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Can you please provide some of work. I want to see the way you play videos one by one.

Comment: So I am using simple Js to set the src when the video end. like **video.src = "second_video.mp4"**

Comment: @PeshrawH.Ahmed  I do not need any js code to do my task. What I want is suggestion on removing the gap between video transtion.

Comment: If you are the author of the player (you wrote "making") then change its behaviour. Otherwise (you just _use_ a player) ask its author for support.

Comment: @AmigoJack So I was forced to write it by myself, as I could not find any optimal solution.

Comment: I think pretty much the only way to achieve this, would be to use a second `video` element, that you use to trigger a pre-loading / buffering of the next video. Might be enough to start that a few seconds before the currently playing video is ending (so that you don’t have two videos loading in parallel for the whole duration.) And then you just switch over to the second video element, once the first has finished playing.

Comment: @04FS Thanks for your suggestion. But I have tried this aproach, it really worked(for 90%). I wanted to know whether other approaches exist.

Comment: there's always going to be a slight discontinuity going from one video to another (even swapping the element), so the only way to do it would be to  present it as a single asset, either using MediaSource on the client side or on-the-fly repackaging (eg to HLS or DASH) on the server

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Thanks for ideas. But can you clarify the option on client side and HLS? I do know about HLS but dunno whether I can do what I want using it.

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is to display all these videos as one video, so that I would not have gaps in switching from video to video.

My first thought was to pre-process the videos clips on demand. Combine into one MP4 using something like `ffmpeg` with a smooth transition between clips (and cache this if it's feasible for your use case). Then you could use a conventional `video.src={pre_processed.mp4}` in the client.

Bountify hosts [an example of using ffmpeg and ffprobe to crossfade two mp4 files](https://bountify.co/php-merge-two-videos-with-a-cross-fade-transition) (see the  selected answer by LayZee).  An abridged version of the function follows. You could use a similar function recursively to customize your own transition and combine files in your directory.

```php
function smoothtransition(
    $videoFilePath1,
    $videoFilePath2,
    $transitionDurationSeconds,
    $outputFilePath,
    $qualityFormatSettings)
{
    $firstVideoDurationCommand = implode(" ", ["...ffprobe_command..."]);
    $firstVideoFileDuration = (float)shell_exec($firstVideoDurationCommand);
    $firstVideoFileFadeStart = $firstVideoFileDuration
        - (float)$transitionDurationSeconds;
    $crossfadeCommand = implode(" ", ["...ffmpeg_command..."]);

    exec($crossfadeCommand, $output, $returnCode);

    return $returnCode === 1 ? $outputFilePath : $returnCode;
}

// Usage:
smoothtransition(
    "{PATH_TO_YOUR_FOLDER}/first_video.mp4",
    "{PATH_TO_YOUR_FOLDER}/second_video.mp4",
    10,
    "{PATH_TO_YOUR_FOLDER}/output_video.mp4",
    null);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this completely client side in javascript instead of taking up server resources?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the basic html video player functionality (As you haven't provided much code to work with), one possibility would be to preload the different videos by including them using different source-tags, and hiding them through various means (changing display or underlaying them beneath the first video) while keeping track of the controls (i.e., pausing/muting them.)
Once your code detects the first video to have stopped, you could then replace its html with the next one you previously hid.

The video source object itself has some interesting parameters you can play with to achieve what you want, too.

Otherwise, you should be able to manually add file request results to a video buffer yourself, [as described in this article.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/fast-playback-with-video-preload#manual_buffering) You might be required to use other libraries as well to make your task easier.

Comment: Yeah, thanks anyway for idea. Thats what I am doing now. Yet, I wanted more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @D.Khumoyun Where exactly are you sourcing the videos from? Is it something quite "dynamic", or could you "physically" join the video files together like someone else suggested? I feel like that would be the most robust approach. Otherwise you could surely do some JavaScript sorcery to pre-load videos in memory before displaying them, but I wouldn't know how to do that off the top of my head. Also, how are the videos distributed? Is it a local application, a website (ie videos downloaded from server while playing), ...?

Comment: @D.Khumoyun Also, I suggest you have a look at this if you havent' already: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/fast-playback-with-video-preload#manual_buffering the article shows you how to manually add to a video buffer.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have TWO different players on the page at the same time at any given moment and pre-buffer the second video while the first one is being watched. Let's assume the following structure (simplified example):

`<video id="video1"></video>`

`<video id="video2" autoplay style="display:none" onloadstart="this.volume=0.0"></video>`

Notice that the first video is visible while the second one is not (CSS). Also, the second video starts buffering and playing as soon as the page loads, but is muted. You will see the benefits of this "pre-buffer" in a second.

You then attach another JS listener to the first video which does the following steps:

1. As soon as playback on the first video ends, it hides player1
2. It shows player2 instead, seeks to position "0 seconds" and unmutes it
3. Since the browser already has some cached/buffered data, there should be minimal to no delay

PS: If you want to go even further, you can unmute and reset the second video 0.5 seconds before the first one ends. In that way you will avoid any possible delays or latency introduced by the browser but you risk overlaping audio if both videos contain some audio in this 0.5 seconds interval.